# Nitrux Icon's Battery indicator symbol is incorrect - how do I fix this?

Tags: themes, icons, faenza

I just have installed Ubuntu 12.10 (fresh new installation) and installed an icon theme pack - Nitrux Icons - and everything is fine, except the battery icon in the system tray.   Here's the icon with the charge adapter unplugged:

[image: unplugged]

And it looks fine - that's the real icon. But when I plug the charger it shows as:

[image: plugged]

Thats not the real icon.
Also, with other themes like Faenza - it shows the same icon when the charger is plugged in.

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: From where did you downloaded the Icons?, [you can see it does have the icon for charging](http://postimage.org/image/tos8zgdot/)

Comment: @UriHerrera I recommend posting something like that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending from where you downloaded the Icons, you may not have the current version of them and yours might not include this particular icon.

As you can see from my screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The current version of the icon set *does contain the icon*. If it's not present in yours please update, if not drop a comment on the Icons page at [deviantART](http://fav.me/d4utllr), I'll check it and see what can be done.